# Laravel how to insert data with post method?

Tags: angular, database, laravel, relation

I've been trying to transfer data from my Angular component using a post method for a few days now. After a long research and reading many documents I still couldn't solve my problem and hope you can help me.

What I'm trying to do is to use a post method to assign the `user_id` and `track_id` fields. I want to add the user and his id to the respective track id after a purchase, but unfortunately I can't get that to work. Do you have any ideas how I can solve that?

I have created a migration called create_trackusers:

```
        Schema::create('trackusers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('track_id');

            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('track_id')->references('trackId')->on('tracklists')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

Here I have created a many to many relationship.
Then I created my Controller:

```
    public function addTrackusers(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $trackusers = User::find($id);

        $trackusers = trackusers::create([
            'user_id'       => $request->name,
            'track_id'      => $request->email
        ]);

        $trackusers->safe();

        return $trackusers;
    }
```

My api.php route looks like that:

```
// Insert Data to trackusers
Route::post('addTrackusers/{id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\trackusersController@addTrackusers');
```

Here I want to assign the `user_id` to his purchased `track_id`.

[image]

**This is how the table should look after a successful entry.**

Here are more details from the models:
trackusers.php:

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id',
        'track_id'
    ];
```

tracklists.php: (Where the tracks are)

```
class tracklists extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    
}
```

User.php:

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'tracks'
    ];
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: what paraments are sending in 'addTrackusers/{id}', api

Comment: `$trackusers->safe();` Typo? `$trackusers->save();`

Comment: In my api I am sending the user_id as parameter to find the user in my controller function. My idea was to assign the user_id with the track_id but unfortunately it just doesn't work. Do you have any advise for me?

Comment: if you want to store track_id with user id send. you should send user_id along with track_id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my understanding.. You can easily map users with tracklists using pivot.  There are a couple nice relationship functions we can use here which are attach() and detach(). So for example, if I were to add a new users to a tracklist, The relationship you need to create is called many-to-many between our tracklists and user model.

```
class tracklists extends Model
 {
    /**
       * The tracklists that belong to many user.
     */
    public function users(){
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\User');
    }
  }
```

And for our User model:

```
class User extends Model
 {
    /**
     * The uses that belong to many tracklists.
   */
    public function tracklists()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany('App\tracklists');
    }
  }
```

**Attach and Detach**,
So how do we actually store the records for our trackusers table?

```
public function addTrackusers(Request $request, $id)
{

    $user = User::find($id);

    $user->tracklists()->attach($request->track_id); // add track
    return $user->tracklists();
}
```

add multiple tracks

```
    public function addTrackusers(Request $request, $id)
{

    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->tracklists()->attach([1,3,7]); // add multiple tracks via an 
 array of track IDs
    return $user->tracklists();
}
```

if you wanted to remove one or more tracklist from a pivot table, uou can use the detatch method:

```
public function removeTrackusers(Request $request, $id)
{

    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->tracklists()->attach($request->track_id); // remove track
    $user->tracklists()->detach([1,3,7]); // remove multiple tracks via an 
 array of track IDs
    return $user->tracklists();
}
```

**Conclusion**
So that's it. Now you know how to use pivot tables with Laravel and Eloquent which is a handy tool to have.

Thankyou, Hope this will help you

Comment: Wow! Sir, thank you so much for the great, detailed answer and for taking the time for me. You've made some things clear to me, it all makes much more sense now. But I got just one question, I keep getting the error with postman: ```Undefined property: Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request::$track_id``` in my trackusersController, is there also a way how I can pass that data? For now I just can pass id from my user, but can I also pass id from my track? Thank you so much Sir.

Comment: I now have the error  ```Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'fullstack_auth.tracklists_user' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `tracklists_user` (`tracklists_id`, `user_id`)``` but, I don't really understand this error. I don't have a column with tracklists_id but track_id, so confusing.

Comment: You need to pass track_id along with user id, which you want to store in pivot table. Can you please tell me how you get track id in function

Comment: If you still stuck with this problem. DM me on twitter, and share meet or zoom link, so i closely see the issue.. https://twitter.com/coderahuljat

Comment: Thank you for the offer. I would be very happy to keep in touch with you, my problem is solved thanks to you! I tried to DM you on twitter but I think the function is disabled on your account. I would then like to write with you when it is activated again. Thanks again for your time and support, without helpers like you there would be no good programmers today! Much appreciated.